# Convert java.sql.Date to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java

Is there a way to convert `java.sql.Date` to `java.sql.Timestamp`?

I have the following code:

```
java.sql.Date = new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date);
```

But the Timestamp constructor doesn't seem to support that variable type.

Comment: Should not it be `java.sql.Date date = new Date();`? Is it a typo or are you missing variable name?

Comment: u can fetch time in milliseconds and then get it converted in my opinion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856931/converting-java-date-to-sql-timestamp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the constructor that takes milliseconds as argument, like:

```
java.sql.Date date = new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```