# How to convert String to TimeStamp

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I want to convert a string to Timestamp. Here is the sample code.

```
I want to parse the string to Timestamp..
```

I have tried to convert it like 
     String date format is "18/01/11";

```
String date = "25/07/2017";
Timestamp ts =Timestamp.valueOf(date);
DateUtil.convertDate(ts.toString());
```

**convertDate:-**

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = inputFormat.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Date Format Not Supported");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        return outputFormat.format(d).toString();
```

if I write like that i am getting the following error

```
Date Format Not Supported
Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Comment: Can you write the actual string down? And there is no sample code!

Comment: Have you considered using a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the `String` to a `Date` value? `18/01/11` is not the same as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: answer is here you can check if it works
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object)

Comment: Please find my edit.. i have added some sample stuff

Comment: what is your input variable value ?

Comment: my input is `ts.toString()`

Comment: in my understanding you have a string, then you want to convert this string to Date object? is that correct?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856931/converting-java-date-to-sql-timestamp .

Comment: Why are you going for an instance of the outdated `java.sql.Timestamp` class? These days I recommend the modern replacement, `java.time.Instant`. A modern JDBC driver (JDBC 4.2 and newer) will be happy to store your `Instant` to your database through `PreparedStatement.setObject()`.

Comment: Also, if your string holds a date without time of day, what would you use a `Timestamp` for? `java.time.LocalDate` would be the appropriate choice (or `java.sql.Date` if for some reason you insist on the old-fashioned classes).

Comment: This question has been asked and answered more than once before. For your own sake, please search before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using just opposite formats if your input format is `dd/MM/yyyy`:

//date format of input

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = null;
try {
    //convert string to date
    d = inputFormat.parse(input);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Date Format Not Supported");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

//output date format

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

//convert date to timestamp

```
return  outputFormat.format(d).toString();
```