# How to select java.util.Date values from Cassandra timestamp type column using Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: timestamp, where-clause, spring-data-cassandra

**Entity class:**

```
 @Table("user")
    public class UserDAO {

    @PrimaryKey
    private UserKey userKey;

    protected UserDAO () {
        super();
    }

    public UserDAO (UserKey userKey, short version) {
        super();
        this. userKey = userKey;
        this.version = version;
    }
    private short version;

    public UserKey getUserKey () {
        return responseTimeKey;
    }

    public void setUserKey(UserKey responseTimeKey) {
        this. userKey = userKey;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        …
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Composite Key Class:**

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class UserKey implements Serializable {

    protected UserKey () {
        super();
    }

    public UserKey (String name, Date date) {
        super();
        this.name = name;       
        this.date = date;

    }


    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String name;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.DESCENDING)
    @CassandraType(type = Name.DATE)
    private Date date;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        …
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        …
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        …
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Repository Interface:**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<UserDAO, UserKey> {
    List<UserDAO> findByUserKeyNameAndUserKeyDate(String name, Date date);

    List<UserDAO> findAll();
}
```

- Date is java.util.Date
- Spring Boot: v2.08
- Spring Data Cassandra:v2.0.8
- Cassandra :  [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4    |
  Native protocol v4]

I am using application.properties to create autowired connection to Cassandra.
When I invoke userRepository.findAll() from controller I get all values with expected Date.

```
[
{
    "userKey": {
        "name": "abc",
        "date": "2018-05-21T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    "version": 1
},
{
    "userKey": {
        "name": "bcd",
        "date": "2018-05-21T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    "version": 1
},
{
    "userKey": {
        "name": "def",
        "date": "2018-05-21T00:00:00.000+0000"
    },
    "version": 1
}
]
```

But when I invoke userRepository.findByUserKeyNameAndUserKeyDate(), below query is triggered and zero results are returned, while passing String name and java.util.Date date as arguments.

**Log:**

```
Created query [SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='abc' AND date=1526841000000;]
```

In **cqlsh** I get result for

```
1.  SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='abc' AND date=toTimestamp('2018-05-21');
2.  SELECT * FROM user WHERE name ='abc' AND date='2018-05-21'
```

**Create Table Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.user (
    name text,
    date timestamp,
    version int,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC)
```

**Table entries:**

```
name    | date                            | version
---------+---------------------------------+---------
    abc | 2018-05-21 00:00:00.000000+0000 |       1
    bcd | 2018-05-21 00:00:00.000000+0000 |       1
    def | 2018-05-21 00:00:00.000000+0000 |       1
```

I tried with java.sql.Timestamp - same result;  com.datastax.driver.core.LocatDate - findAll() gave cannot convert java.util.Date to LocalDate and findByUserKeyNameAndUserKeyDate() gave same result.

Please help on how to query by date and what am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `java.util.Date` anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried with Timestamp, LocalDate and then lastly java.util.Date.

Comment: If you could not avoid to use `java.util.Date`, you could try to convert to timestamp. Please,  check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856931/converting-java-date-to-sql-timestamp